# Facebook Business "Additional Contact Details" Email Pending

Tags: facebook, email

I changed the email address on my Facebook Business page's "Additional Contact Details" section and confirmed it, but it still says it's pending - why? Are they reviewing the email address or is there something else I can do to get it accepted already?

Comment: Check in other browser? Clear the cache of current browser and check if it solve the issue.

Comment: Did you get an email with a confirmation link, maybe in your spam folder? How long has it been pending?